# Inherit DialogFragment from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inheritance, dialogfragment

Can I inherit DialogFragment from Fragment

I mean say I have a fragment (ABC_Fragment) and this fragment shows item details (images, buttons, labels...)
for some reasons i have to show the same fragment(XML and Java code) in dialogfragment (popup window)

I don't want to copy the same code to new dialogfragment class

how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed

it is called 
Selecting Between Dialog or Embedding

as described in the above link you can select how to show the DialogFragment either as a Dialog or as usual use (normal)